# Composite query in Perl API of Berkeley DBXML

Tags: perl, berkeley-db-xml

I need to do a composite query to my dbxml container from Perl and I can´t afford to do it. In SQL it would be like this:

```
select * from books where ISBN='123' AND year='1994';
```

The `and` I wrote is the problem.  I don´t know how to do it in bdbxml from Perl.